# bootstrap overlay list group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to give a button slide in effect just for a mock up using bootstrap lists and overlays. I want to make it look like the button is coming in from the right. [Here](http://www.bootply.com/UqiJbICpfz) is the code for what Im trying to do. I'm trying give the li element a positive relative and z-index so it is "above" the .pull-right div.

Any idea what I could do for this to work? The button labeled Test should look like it is coming in from the right, therefore half the text should be visible and half should be not.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? So the button is coming (moving) from the right? What is the trigger for the movement (on Document Load, on list mouseover, etc.)? Bootstrap doesn't provide animation, you can either use css animation or jQuery.

Comment: I don't need to worry about the animation right now. Just need the button to be kind of hidden relative to the li element.

Comment: well, can't you just set the moving element with a negative right margin? then, when triggered, reset margin

Answer (score 0):

*As per my understanding I think you might have to hide the overflow of the `li`*

So, I added a class to your html structure

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item pos-rel overflow-x-fix">
    <p class="inline-block">Test</p>
    <div class="pull-right pos-abs">
      <button>Text</button>
      <button>Test</button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And changed the CSS like this

```
inline-block{
  display: inline-block;  
  }

  .pos-rel{
     position: relative;
      z-index: 999;
   }

    .pos-abs{
       position: absolute;
        right: -2%;
        top: 20%;
        z-index: 1;
      }

.overflow-x-fix {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Here is the [example](http://www.bootply.com/46XBBuYtOV)